# TCP/IP server/client multiconnection using C# and receiving public ip address of client

Tags: c#, tcp

I need to write an application using C#, which will connect a client to a server with a static IP address.

The server and clients must be able to send and receive message at the same time. Also, I need to log the information with respect of clients public address as well.

How can I make it using C#?

Shall I use `TcpListener` / `TcpClient` or is there any other method which can make multiple connections?

Comment: Your question in your current format is too broad. Actually you ask us to code this for you. Give it a try and tell us what the problems are you experience.

Comment: I have tried it, but i cant make multiple connections, and i cant receive clients public ip address, currently i am using TCPlistener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to go low level to TCP/IP and own message parse/serialize/deserialize, you can use SocketAsyncEventArgs for high performance code, but it is not as easy as with TCPListener/TCPClient.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod

Question is, why not to use for example WCF/IIS ?

Comment: if i use SocketAsyncEventArgs, am i able to communicate with multiple client at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, you can communicate with 1000 clients at the same time. IMO best performance if you insist on c#